# Which PayPal API should we use for marketplace (ebay model)?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, payment, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

We have a marketplace where farmers can sell their products. Any user can buy multiple items from several sellers and our platform has 10% fee from every transaction.

Now we use Chained Payments (which is incorrect, because marketplace account is a primary receiver) with fees model where every recipient pays PayPal fees.

Which PayPal API should we use for a transaction where can be several sellers and marketplace account (has 10% from products cost) so marketplace account wouldn't pay PayPal fee?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would have a buyer, a seller, and the marketplace in the transaction.

Is there a reason why you couldn't just use chained payments, set the seller to be the primary receiver (see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/), the marketplace to the secondary receiver, and then set the `feesPayer` option to either `PRIMARYRECEIVER` (seller) or `SENDER` (buyer) so that one of them pays all the fees?

Comment: But I can have at most one primary receiver. And it isn't suitable for cases where we have several sellers.

Comment: In that case, the Braintree marketplace offering will most likely be closest to what you're looking for: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/braintree-marketplace/. It's the same type of structure that Uber / AirBnB use. Here are more details on service fees: https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/marketplace/processing